# regex to find lines starting with `*` and ending with `)` in eclipse using regex search

Tags: regex, eclipse, shell, grep

I am trying to use this regular expressing in Eclipse to find the lines mentioned below.

I have a text file `text.txt`:

```
teeet()
*test()
*test
* ()
test 
asdgaer ()
* test()
```

I want to find the regex to find all the lines that starts with `*` and ends with `)`

Sample output :

```
*test()
* ()
* test()
```

Here is what I have so far :

```
grep "^\* . )$" Test.txt
```

The output was blank.

I tried :

```
grep "^\*" Test.txt
```

The out put is :

```
*test()
*test
* ()
* test()
```

Also tried :

```
grep ")$" Test.txt
```

The output was :

```
teeet()
*test()
* ()
asdgaer ()
* test()
```

Combined them, they didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Use single quotes, not double, surrounding grep's regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep '^\*.*)$' file
*test()
* ()
* test()
```

Or else:

```
grep -E '^\*.*\)$' file
```

You must keep `.*` between starting `*` an ending `)` match any arbitrary data in between.

Comment: I tried ussing `^\*.*)$` in Eclipse regex, but it said unmatched closing near ) near index 4.

Comment: In Eclipse you must use `^\*.*\)$'` with escaped `(`.

Comment: I did try that. It still didn't work. I am certain the texts are there.

Comment: You tried `grep` command or regex in Eclipse? Both `grep` commands are well tested.

Comment: `regex` in eclipse, your solution is perfect for `grep`

Comment: I would say don't mix `grep` with `Eclipse`. Question is about `grep` and `shell` and Eclipse is totally different regex flavor. **However `^\*.*\)$` worked perfectly for me on Eclipse as well.**

Comment: `^\t.\*.*\)$` I totally Ignored the tabs, I am sorry.

Comment: `grep -E '^\t.*\)$' file` works. But don't mix this with `Eclipse` issue. There can be editor settings in Eclipse that can change tab to space etc. Probably Eclipse doesn't even recognize `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` is also handy for this kind of checkings:

```
$ awk '/^*/ && /)$/' file
*test()
* ()
* test()
```

- `/^*/` checks if the line starts with `*`.
- `/)$/` checks if the line ends with `)`.

With the `&&` between we make sure both things happen.